# How can I show that this function is discontinuous at the point $x=1$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, continuity

Suppose you had the function
$$
f(x) = \; \text{ the integer part of } x
$$
I wish to show that this is not continuous at the point $x=1$, which I will try to do by showing that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} f(x)$ does not exist. To do this, I use a direct $\varepsilon - \delta$ proof of convergence. That is, show that for some arbitrary value of $\varepsilon$ there exists no value of $\delta$ such that
$$
0 < |x-1| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon
$$
I am not sure where to go from here. Can anyone please help.

Comment: Try $\varepsilon=1/2$

Comment: Notice that $0.9, 0.99, 0.999\cdots\to0$ while $1.1, 1.01,1.001\cdots\to1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $0<x<2$ you know that $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0,& x<1\\1, & 1\le x\end{cases}$$ and for any $δ>0$ $$B_δ(1):=\{x:1-δ< x< 1+δ\}=\{x: |x-1|<δ\}$$ So, for any $δ>0$ there are $x$'s in $B_δ(1)$ such that $f(x)=0$ and $x$'s in $B_δ(1)$ such that $f(x)=1$. Can you take it from here, by choosing an appropriate value for $ε$?

---

Take an $0<ε<1$ ($0$ and $1$ are the two values of $f$), for example $ε=0.5$ and take any $δ>0$. Assume the existence of an $L$ such that $$|f(x)-L|<ε \implies -0.5+L< f(x)< L+0.5$$ From this $L+0.5$ must be necessarily $> 1$ since $f(x)$ takes value $1$ on $B_δ(1)$ which implies $L> 0.5$ but also $-0.5+L$ must be $<0$ since $f(x)$ takes value $0$ on $B_δ(1)$ which implies $L< 0.5$ a contradiction. Any other $0<ε<1$ would do.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively,

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^-} f(x)= 0 \neq 1 =\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^+} f(x)$$

Comment: He wanted an $\epsilon$ $\delta$ proof.

Comment: I am just providing an alternative approach.

Comment: This answers the question in the title but not the question in the text.

Comment: OK, but I think it would be more appropriate as a _comment_ since it does not directly help him answer the question.

Comment: I somewhat disagree. OP "wishes to show $f(x)$ is not continuous at $x=1$" by showing that the limit does not exist. I am offering an alternative approach to this method.